# How i can provide variables from scrapy to python script?

Tags: python, scrapy

I started scrapy from python:

```
from gsaadvantage.spiders.gsaadvantage_crawler import GsaadvantageCrawlerSpiderfrom twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = GsaadvantageCrawlerSpider()
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the spider_closed signal was sent
```

But How i can get data from scrapy (etc list of strings) to python main script?
Thank you!